# Which Latin manuscripts were used by the KJV translators?

Tags: bible-translation, kjv, latin, kjv-onlyism

When the KJV translators set out to do their translation, they gathered all existing manuscripts and translations they could, to make sure they had everything absolutely right.

I am curious, which Latin scriptures did they use?

I am aware they had some, but not which.

Comment: I myself am a KJV Bible Believer, but I was thinking about learning Latin (reconstructed classical pronunciation, not ecclesiastical,) and I understand how the grammar works, but would like something I know is going to be a little closer to the KJV. That, and a friend asked which they used.

Comment: The Latin Vulgate was consulted, but the primary texts were Greek and Hebrew. It's all covered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version).

Comment: I am aware, they primarily used the Masoretic texts(which are mostly lost) and then reconstructed a Greek based off of a few different textís receptís. But I thank you. I assumed the Vulgate was used, but I was unsure if it was the only latin text.

Comment: Look up what you may find on the *Codex Claromontanus* this is the Codex that Theodore Beza purchased In Claremont (Greek/Latin Unicle Manuscript...